# Error:Object reference not set to an instance of an object?

Tags: c#, asp.net

There is an error i.e. Object reference not set to an instance of an object, i am trying to compare security question and answer using email id which are present in database using below
code

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

{

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\keishna\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MasterDemo\App_Data\Earth_Movers.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
        con.Open();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Security_Question,Answer FROM Registration Where email='" + TextBox3.Text + "'", con);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(ds,"data");
        //string Ans = (cmd.ExecuteReader()).ToString();
        string sq = (ds.Tables["0"]).ToString();
        string Ans = (ds.Tables["1"]).ToString();
        if (sq == TextBox3.Text && Ans == TextBox2.Text)
        {
            Response.Redirect("NewPassword.aspx?email="+TextBox3.Text);
        }
    }
```

but error is here

```
**string sq = (ds.Tables["0"]).ToString();
            string Ans = (ds.Tables["1"]).ToString();**
```

using this code i am taking email id as query string and sending it to `NewPassword.aspx` page where i can set new passsword and update this using email id for changing particular column.

and NewPassword.aspx code has a button,on a button click new password should get updated in registration table and login table of my database.

```
NewPassword.aspx code

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public partial class Webpages_NewPassword : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 

    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\krishna\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MasterDemo\App_Data\Earth_Movers.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
        con.Open();
        if (Request.QueryString["email"] != null)
        {
            string Email= Request.QueryString["email"];
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update Registration set Password where email='" + Email + "'", con);
        }
        con.Close();

    }
}
```

So please provide me solution as soon as possible.

Thanks and Regards

Vasundara Reddy

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 5):

One of these things is `null`.

```
ds
ds.Tables
ds.Tables["0"]
ds.Tables["1"]
```

Are you sure you don't mean this instead?

```
ds.Tables[0]
ds.Tables[1]
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the index of the table as `int`, so instead of

```
string sq = (ds.Tables["0"]).ToString();
```

this

```
string sq = (ds.Tables[0]).ToString();
```

Since your `DataSet` does not contain a table with the name `"0"` it returns `null`.

The name of your table is `"data"`, because you have used the overload of [`DataApter.Fill`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y4b211hz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that takes the name of the table it should fill.

So this works also:

```
string sq = (ds.Tables["data"]).ToString();
```

**However**, i'm sure that you don't want `DataTable.ToString` but the content of it's row(s):

```
DataTable data = ds.Tables["data"];
string firstQuestion = data.Rows[0].Field<string>("Security_Question");
string firstAnswer = data.Rows[0].Field<string>("Answer");
```

Comment: how to compare data of database with textbox value.its like i have security question and answer which should be compared and then moved to NewPassword.aspx and then user can update his new password

Comment: @user3384492: i have edited my answer to show you how you read the rows fields. You can loop them if the table contains multiple via `DataTable.Rows`.

Comment: Now there is no error but not redirected to NewPassword.aspx